# How do you testfor certain items are on the ground?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, I'm trying to make an "Only One Command" thing by hand for the first time, and I need to use the "*Floor Crafting*" technique. But, the thing is, I can't testfor or delete a CERTAIN item. For example, I want to delete a block of sand that's a Tile Entity(Item). How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can run this in a clock:

```
/testfor @e[type=Item]
```

If you need to test an certain item, You can use this:

```
/testfor @e[type=Item] {Item:{id:**Change me to block id!**}}
```

There!

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the {Item} NBT tag.

Comment: If you need to use a command that doesn't support NBT matching (`kill`, `execute`, etc.), you can assign a scoreboard score to the item entity first, then use it in your target selector.

Comment: @MrLemon Yup! That works too.